# measure indicators: custom text

Tags: inkscape, measurement

[image]

In Inkscape, I try to "name" some dimensions (*x, h, d* etc).

What is the "classic" way to add such indicators like in picture? I don't need to *measure*, but to **name** a dimension.

- for `b` I tried "path effects"=> "measure segments", that is painful, I can't place the letter in the middle of the line and give enough space around.
- for the `gc` I need to display the distance between the middle of the circle and the upper border... impossible, I needed to add a transparent rectangle but I can't get rid of the line in the middle

Related GitHub issue
https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/3488

Comment: You draw the elements. Or if you must use text on path. Inkscape is direct modeling tool, its meant to draw things manually. While there are some convenience functions to do certain things with tools automatically, the tool itself is not designed with this in mind. There is no overarching system that can do prettymuch everything you want effotlessly, because every indirect modeling tool is an afterthought. Except maybe if draw everything manually is considered effortless.

Comment: @joojaa, I just ask if there is a way to do it in Inkscape. "Is not possible" is an answer among others, just to know

Comment: @serge sure, "is not possible" is harder to prove. But obviously its possible to do by making each text, line arrow and lines manually. Im not sure if it is possible to automate or not though. Like i said the system is not consistent so its hard to evaluate where it fails. I am just pointing out that it is not unusual for the software to make you do it manually, since doing it manually is the softwares core design purpose (nothing wrong with that).

Comment: @joojaa OP don't really care to evaluate "where the system fails"... there is a practice question, not theory about big data.

Comment: added related issue in github https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/3488

Comment: Sure just pointing out that the answer may take a long time to come as nobody likes to answer not possible (because it is hard to prove). Ive just built a motivation as to why that is likely the case that its not possible. Nothing to do with big data.

Comment: You should really avoid opening issues in the main tracker. Instead, you should open the issue on Inbox: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues

Comment: @s.ouchene why in inbox and not in the main tracker?

Comment: it could be a duplicate of another issue.

Comment: @s.ouchene, and what's preventing the creation of the duplicate in inbox?

Comment: Your issue will be likely closed because the recommended way is always to post the issue/or the feature requests in INBOX. Note that we have also chat.inkscape.org to discuss that.

Comment: @s.ouchene so how external people are aware of your internal rules, of what to put where? at the moment the issue tracker is open to public, should you close issues just because of a unknown rule nobody knows?

Comment: @serge: Sorry for that. It is documented here: https://inkscape.org/contribute/report-bugs/

Comment: @s.ouchene what exactly is documented in the above link? I don't find the word "inbox" in the referenced page

Comment: @serge: https://i.imgur.com/rt4YLYr.png

Comment: @s.ouchene I see, but imagine the % of people who click on that link versus people searching on google or hitting here https://pasteboard.co/DZhR0HROGKDM.png

Comment: Sorry, this disucssion is getting longer here, and it's irrelevant to GDSE, let's continue on chat.inkscape.org

Answer (score 2):

Finally, even not without pain, there is a way to achieve it, using Path Effects (Menu Path=>Path Effects).
[image]

Some mentions here:

- the extension is unstable, and we should sometimes **force the redrawing** by fake changing some options to refresh the needed display
- in order to **add multiple text dimensions**, we need to add multiple paths effects to the same path
- in order to measure **distance between two different paths**, we need to create fake invisible paths between them, and apply the effect to that invisible path
- in order to **change texts, apply format** to it, is possible to right click on the text, then "unlock" the object, then edit is available
- in order to have **more white space** around the text, I added just empty spaces in the text field

Comment: thanks @s.ouchene for your suggestions and help

Comment: Another workaround is to use Tikz with the textText extension. Here are some example of technical drawing using Tikz: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz